# Why do we have $\frac{13 y}{5} +y = \frac{13y+5y}{5}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have this expression:

$$\dfrac{13y}{5}+y.$$

My text book then goes on and writes the above as:

$$\dfrac{13y+5y}{5}$$

I don't understand why the $5$ was given to the $y$ variable without affecting the $5$ in the denominator.

Comment: First that is not an equation.  Second, it is simply getting a common denominator to add fractions: $\frac{13y}{5}+ y= \frac{13y}{5}+ \frac{5y}{5}= \frac{13y+ 5y}{5}= \frac{18y}{5}$

Comment: $$y=\dfrac{5y}{5}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wondering why it is so then,

Multiply $5$ on each side.

The right hand side becomes $$\frac{13y}{5} \times 5+y \times 5 =5y+13y$$

Dividing $5$ gives us that $$\frac{13y}{5}+y=\frac{13y+5y}{5}$$

I will delete this answer if you know this.

Comment: Gotcha. I got 18y as I supposed to get. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I suspect a typo in the fraction, for a reduction to the same denominator. A working example could be:
$$\frac{13y}{5}+y = \frac{13y+5y}{5}.$$

Comment: yes, I will fix that.

Comment: My word! That is quite astonishing. I wouldn't be surprised if you were reading from a math textbook by an Indian author. I have seen ever so many typos, and some of them are quite astonishing,like this, even worse ones. There was a question once where they asked for the  integrals of $17$ quite complicated functions, and well-at the back of the book everybody found the derivatives.

Comment: Hahaha! That is great.

Comment: No, but the typo was my fault